# How to ignore "if" arguments Lua

Tags: lua, arguments, call

I want to bypass/ignore the returns from "if" arguments in global.
example. (x y represent misc arg)

global script line 1

```
if x == y then
os.exit()
return
end

function HOME() 
    -- some codes
end 

HOME()

-- end script
```

I'll be loading this script from another script by using pcall(..

I want to know,  how to ignore all global arguments, so when that script goes straight to HOME() if this is even possible.  also,  I'll be doing this from android phone,  using a program that has limited lua functions,  things like popen, execute are disabled
I know if I write in the main script

```
pcall("script above")
HOME()
```

I can goto HOME() but only if the script above runs completely through correctly (editing the script is also not an option,  I could do

```
os.exit=print
pcall(
```

but the "return" still exits the script

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to ignore the `return`? What about the `os.exit`? This seems to be an X-Y-problem to me. Just make sure that the `if` doesn't fire by setting `x ~= y` or by adding another condition that must be met using `and`:

Comment: sorry..  will try to explain better. (thanks for the reply) script A = the script with the "if". I'm running script "A" by using Script "B" in pcall.  I want to know if there is a way to ignore all arguments. or to ignore "return" so script doesn't exit and continues to HOME().  I can bypass os.exit() by stating prior to pcall that os.exit=print.  so now script will do.    if x==y then print() return end.    but that return still exits script.   is there a way to just ignore the "if" all together or a way to ignore "return" so script doesn't exit

Comment: DEMONVIC: Well, how do you pass the args?

Comment: "if x==y then.. " was just an example to show the flow of the script.  "if "some argument ==/~=/>/< etc" then return end...  can lua be told that when it sees "if" to just ignore it and go to the next line?  if not,  is there any way so that the "return" in my example can be ignored?  (I don't think there is any way though) note- I can't edit this script,  and is running by a pcall.  the most I can do are things like os.exit=print..  things like this before doing the pcall

Comment: You can do `if false then ... end` to never go into the `if` block of code, if that's what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: thank you all for your time and replies,  but I think the problem with my question is the ability to explain myself.   thanks again everyone,  really do appreciate you

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the environment for the function.

```
local function some_script()
    if x == y then
        print("Bye!")
        os.exit()
        return
    end

    function HOME()
        print("HOME!")
    end

    HOME()
end

-- code calling the "script"

local fn = some_script -- alt: use loadfile/load

local dummy = 1
local myenv = {}
setmetatable(myenv, {
    __index = function (self, key)
        -- check here if you want to "overwrite" the variables
        if key == "x" or key == "y" then
            dummy = dummy + 1
            return dummy
        end

        return _G[key]
    end
})

setfenv(fn, myenv)
fn() -- prints: HOME!
```